# Insert machine code into C code at runtime

Tags: c, avr

I am currently building some stuff with an Arduino Uno/Nano using the C language, and I need to insert some already compiled code from outside into the executable at runtime.

I want to be able to use it like a dynamically linked library, that I can exchange within the program.

Here is some code to show what I mean:

```
int external_code(int); // the external code needs to be called some way
void set_external_code(char*); // set the external code that gets executed
```

Comment: Arduino is not C! And AVR is a harvard architecture and not well suited for dynamically loading code. Also Assembly code has to be translated before usage. If you mean **machine** code: that's something very different.

Comment: @Olaf The Arduino is just using an AVR chip, and I compile C to create the needed bytecode.

Comment: @Olaf I meant machine code

Comment: @MByD Does it really matter? It's currently an Arduino Uno, but the final project will run under an Arduino Nano.

Comment: The you should remove the Arduino-tag and change to AVR and C. "Arduino" implies the language for a software site like this one! The rest of my comments still apply.

Comment: It actually does. on most AVRs you cannot run code from RAM, and there is separation between code and data, but on ARM based you might be able to do so.

Comment: @MByD Thank you for that information...

Comment: @MByD Do you think that an Arduino MKRZero (it runs on an ARM architecture) is able to load program code at runtime?

Comment: An AVR based Arduino can probably not do this. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @AShelly I am trying to be able to adjust a curve that is controlling how much the motor should move from another device.

Comment: So turn the curve into data instead of code.  Use a combination of variables (and function pointers if needed) to change the control system,

Comment: @AShelly That is what I planned to do instead anyway. But that makes performance worse and limits the amount of possible shapes of the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to load extra program code over serial, you can't do that.

From the [Arduino docs](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Memory):

> Note: Flash (PROGMEM) memory can only be populated at program burn time. You can’t change the values in the flash after the program has started running.

AVR stores programs in separate physical memory (Flash). You can read from it, but can't write at runtime unlike RAM and EEPROM.